# Error: unable to verify the first certificate in API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, https, make.com

I'm searching for some help with my API HTTPS calls.

Here is the problem:

I'm calling my API through platforms like Integromat and Adalo for a project.
But each time I try to call it I receive the following error :

```
UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE: unable to verify the first certificate
```

I tried to use the server with HTTP, it is working for simple calls but on Adalo it gets blocked because I'm not using HTTPS.

The certificates I'm using are not self signed, they are delivered by Ionos.

Here is my API server code:

```js
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import cors from 'cors'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
import cron from 'node-cron'
import https from 'https'
import fs from 'fs'
import { db } from './models/index.js'
import freeDatesRoutes from './routes/freeDates.routes.js'
import lockedDatesRoutes from './routes/lockedDates.routes.js'
import axios from 'axios'

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.cer'),
    passphrase: process.env.DBPASSWORD
}, app).listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
})
db.config.authenticate()

app.use('/api/v1/freeDates', freeDatesRoutes)
app.use('/api/v1/lockedDates', lockedDatesRoutes)
app.get('/api/v1', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to AirRental API')
})

cron.schedule('0 3 * * *', () => {
    console.log("Starting schedule ", new Date())
    axios.post(`https://localhost:5000/api/v1/freeDates/booking/all`)
})
```

Do you have any idea how to get rid of this error and still using HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the server was simply missing the Intermediate certificate.

And we can set it just like that:

```js
https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.cer'),
    ca: [ fs.readFileSync('./inter.cer') ],
    passphrase: process.env.DBPASSWORD
}, app).listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
})
```